# The different local network speed on identical network adapters

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, networking

I have 2 PC with identical motherboard, first ubuntu 14.04, second ubuntu 16.04.
And there are the different speed in local network. 
14.04 give 100 Mbits and 16.04 give 1000 Mbits.

Maybe there are different settings in ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: What are the network cards in each? Please edit your question to add the details from both from the terminal command: `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Might be just different cables or lan ports? Please give more details about your hardware setup

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, because you didn't give the smallest hint about your network hardware (downvoted for that):

Ubuntu 14.04 may not have adequate drivers for your network hardware, but at least it got it working at 100Mbit.

Ubuntu 16.04 includes some more drivers and found one that knows how to enable 1000Mbit. Be happy ;-)